# Running Excel Function in Access - Issues with Parameters

Tags: excel, vba, function, ms-access, import

Having some trouble streamlining the database creation process in Access. As it stands, I have a bunch of 'raw' .csv files, and a macro to convert them. The macro prompts the user to select file(s) to convert, then converts and saves them. The macro also exists as a function that takes an object consisting of one or more files as an argument, converts and saves them, as well as returns the filename(s) of the converted files. I then import these converted files to Access.

I'm trying to set things up so one button click on a form in Access will convert the raw files, then import them into Access.

I've followed the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700561/using-ms-access-to-run-code-in-excel-vba), and can get the stand-alone macro to run, but am struggling to call the function (which takes an argument) to run.

Any help is appreciated. If more information is required, please let me know.

Comment: It's best to include your actual code in your question, and show how you've tried to call it and what error(s) you got when you tried that.

Comment: @mitchpehora  Simply give the arguments separated with a colon: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-run-method-excel

Comment: @TimWilliams please see my update :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661823/how-do-i-convert-excel-files-then-import-to-access-in-one-step